# How do I empty a Tabulator table for reuse?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am new to `Tabulator` and I am trying to programmatically empty a `Tabulator table` so it can be reused.  I found information in the documentation relating to the `deleteRow` method and have attempted to use it as follows:

```
const memberTableId = $(mydiv).attr("id");
const tablesMember = Tabulator.prototype.findTable(memberTableId);
if (tablesMember.length > 0) {
    const tableCrewMember = Tabulator.prototype.findTable(memberTableId)[0];
    const dataCrewMember = tableCrewMember.getData();
    for (i = 0; i < dataCrewMember.length; i++) {
        tableCrewMember.deleteRow([i]);
    }
}
```

The `findTable` and `getData` methods work as advertised and I have no problem iterating through the data array; however, I can't seem to find a way to make the `deleteRow` function work for me.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick option would be to simply set the data on the table to an empty array:

```
tableCrewMember.setData([]);
```

Done!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I'm also having an issue with the ``Tabulator rowTapHold`` method not working with iOS devices.  I have reported the issue in the following SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61787592/5425510   Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.